# Flight DC → Toronto → Vancouver → Sydney. Have to take out luggage at Vancouver?

Tags: air-travel, canada, air-canada

We're travelling from DC to Sydney, using the above route. ([Google Flights link](https://www.google.com/flights/?curr=USD#search;f=DCA;t=SYD;d=2016-12-17;tt=o;sel=DCAYYZ0AC7615-YYZYVR0AC33-YVRSYD0AC33)).

[image: Google Flights]

On the booking page, AirCanada says that during the 1h30 in Vancouver,

1. we have to take out luggage and clear custom
2. check-in at the domestic terminal even though it is an international flight

[image: Screenshot of the AirCanada's note]

My two questions are:

1. Is there any reason for this weird requirement at Vancouver? Shouldn't custom be cleared in Toronto, our first stop in Canada?
2. 1h30 doesn't seem nearly enough for transiting. However, this seems like AirCanada's routine Toronto-Sydney flight, and they supposedly do this all the time. Does anyone have experience transiting on this route? Is 1h30 okay?

Comment: This seems likely to be an error.  Maybe call the airline to check?

Comment: There is no *exit* customs in Canada. You'll pass through *entry* customs (when arriving from the US in Toronto - it's always done at your first point of entry). Your luggage will then likely be checked straight through to Sydney, but check with the airline to be sure (even if it's not, there won't be a customs check in Vancouver).

Comment: @NateEldredge I called twice, and even though the reps seemed rather clueless, they did confirm the policy. One guy even called the "operation people," and those people confirmed.

Comment: Weeeeeeeeeird.  You made it clear to them that you are *only* traveling outbound to Sydney, and not returning?  The message would make perfect sense for the other direction SYD-YVR-YYZ.  There's absolutely no logical reason to do customs and immigration as you *leave* Canada.

Comment: Regarding the "check in at domestic terminal", I suspect this means that you check in at the domestic terminal *in Toronto*, which would make sense because the first leg of the flight is in fact domestic.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I agree with you about "domestic terminal" because the same note appears if you book YYZ->YVR on AC033, but it is weird since only YVR has something you could describe as a "domestic terminal". YYZ has 2 terminals, divided by airline group; both handle domestic and international flights.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will go through Canadian immigration and customs in Toronto, not Vancouver. I am not sure why it says what it says; maybe it means for the return flight.

Comment: Do you have a source / personal experience with this route?